# Calling an executable within a nested for loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to call an executable with two arguments within a nested for loop (I'm also writing in bash scripting). I thought I was doing it correctly, but all my values show up in the text file as 0. i.e. tilt 0 angle 0 even though the values are obviously not. My code is as such:

```
for (( i=0; i <=3; i++)); do
    for (( j=0; j <= 3; j++ )); do
        ./solar_sim 'i' 'j' >> solarResults.txt
        echo -n "$i"
    done
    echo " "
done
```

`

The solar_sim was provided to us and output a line like this, which I write to a file:

`10000 hours, angle: 0.00 degrees, temperature: 0.00 degrees C, total power: 119871.00 Watts`

Am I doing something wrong in the calling of solar_sim? I also tried using $i and $j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is this line :

```
./solar_sim 'i' 'j' >> solarResults.txt
```

should be rewritten like this :

```
./solar_sim "$i" "$j" >> solarResults.txt
```

Also, `echo` is sufficient alone, no need `echo " "` to print a newline

Comment: Oops! Forgot the double quotes. Thanks so much!

Comment: Not only the double quotes but the _sigils_

Comment: I'm pretty new to bash scripting, so I was experimenting. Got the sigils in. Thanks. Will upvote when able

Comment: Yes, I know. I had to wait the required amount of time. No need to be rushed!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you forgot the "$" to de-reference the i and j variables

```
./solar_sim "$i" "$j" >> solarResults.txt
```

Comment: Where's there's references ? This is just some basic variables... And in single quotes, variables are not interpolated !

Comment: Excuse me if my terminology is not perfect.  It sure looked to me like the script was intending to reference the variables value.